# cannot send email using gmail account from android using javax

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, jakarta-mail, gmail-api

Error sending email:

> returns 451 4.5.0 `SMTP protocol` violation, see RFC 2821
>   g5sm13340466pfg.0 - gsmtp.

After getting the `oauth token`, type and oauth expire from `gmail`.

here the following code used to test send email using `oauth2`.

```
private String GenerateOAuth2String(boolean base64_encode){
        String OAuthString = "";
        Log.e("SendTestActivity", "AuthToken: " + authToken);
        OAuthString = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", userName, authToken);
        Log.e("SendTestActivity", "non base 64: " + OAuthString);
        if (base64_encode)
            OAuthString = Base64.encodeToString(OAuthString.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.e("SendTestActivity", "base 64: " + OAuthString);
        return OAuthString;
    }

    private synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String user, String recipients) {
        try {           
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "false");

            session = Session.getInstance(props);
            session.setDebug(true);

            final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
            SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, unusedUrlName);
            // If the password is non-null, SMTP tries to do AUTH LOGIN.
            final String emptyPassword = null;
            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, user, emptyPassword);

            transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + GenerateOAuth2String(true),
                    235);

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));

             // Set To: header field of the header.
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));

             // Set Subject: header field
             message.setSubject(subject);

             // Now set the actual message
             message.setText(body);

            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
            else  
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   

            Transport.send(message);

            Log.e("SendTestActivity", "email sent");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SendTestActivity", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

is there something wrong with the setup?

also does the \1 in user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1 a "string" or a "start of heading" character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it the hard way.  [Let JavaMail do it for you.](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2)

Comment: Hi, I am using JavaMail, but it only shows how to connect to read messages through imap, what i am intending to do is send messages through smtp

Comment: If you follow the link, it explains how you only have to replace "imap" with "smtp" in the property names.  Was that not clear?

Comment: In case you're still confused, this is the [send method](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send-javax.mail.Message-javax.mail.Address:A-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) you want to use.

Comment: hi the send method requires the password does it mean that the oauth token will be placed in the password section? and yes I am still confused

Comment: hi, was able to send using the link you gave, I though the password parameter is for the actual password of the user's account, but then when I compare to the Store.connect's method the oauth token is also placed in the password parameter so when I tried to pass the oauth token in the password parameter of Transport.send function it works and my mail account the received the email. thanks very much.

Comment: Right, as it says on the [JavaMail OAuth2 page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2), "The access token is passed as the password ...".

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried giving permission here:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Some of the errors like that are because you don't have the complete properties, complements with this:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

Comment: Hi, this is old style and may not be supported in the future, using oauth2 you are not required to turn on lesssecureapps, plus it is more secure, you cannot just let users of your app to allow less secure app, it will make there email vulnerable